# Unable to display generated HTML ,from Showdown plugin, in React component

Tags: reactjs, showdown

I'm using Showdown module to obtain HTML from markdown. I want to display the generated HTML in my React component. My converter is working fine generating the HTML: `<h1 id="typeyourmarkdownbountyhere">Type your markdown bounty  here…</h1>`

But I get this error message: `Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element.`
Is there another/better way to display the generated HTML? Can anyone point what I'm doing wrong?

```js
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite"
import React from "react"
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Showdown from 'showdown'

import { useStore } from "../store/Provider"

const converter = new Showdown.Converter({
    tables: true,
    simplifiedAutoLink: true,
    strikethrough: true,
    tasklists: true,
})

function Bounties() {
    const store = useStore()

    return (
        store.bounties.map( bounty => (
        <div>
            <h3 key={bounty.id}>{bounty.title}</h3> 
            <div id="bountyBody"></div>
            {ReactDOM.render(converter.makeHtml(bounty.body), document.getElementById('bountyBody')) }
        </div>
        ))
    )
}

export default observer(Bounties)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is thrown because you are trying to get a reference to a DOM node while it has still to be rendered on DOM itself. You could solve it by calling `ReactDOM.render` inside a `useEffect` with an empty deps array [], this way it would be executed after the first render, but you will notice that it would anyway not work as expected, since it will render a string representing HTML code, it won't parse it!    `ReactDOM.render` is used to attach *JSX* code to a DOM node, while you are trying to pass an *HTML string* ( that' s what `converter.makeHtml()` returns ). So it would never work.

A working approach would be:

- Convert Markdown to HTML
- Transpile HTML/JSX to React first level API
- Parse the transpiled code
- Execute it as real JSX code

This is an example :

```
import React, { useMemo, useEffect } from 'react';
import Showdown from 'showdown';
const buble = require('buble');

const MarkdownToJSX = ({ md }) => {
  if (typeof md !== 'string') return null;
  const makeComponent = useMemo(() => {
    const converter = new Showdown.Converter({
      tables: true,
      simplifiedAutoLink: true,
      strikethrough: true,
      tasklists: true,
    });
    const html = `<>${converter.makeHtml(md)}</>`;
    const code = buble.transform(html).code;
    const makeComponent = Function('React', 'return ' + code);
    return makeComponent;
  }, [md]);

  return makeComponent(React);
};
```

Check the working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-32m1ay

Comment: Thanks @Cesare , It worked perfectly. I just had to add this directive `// eslint-disable-next-line` before `const makeComponent = Function('React', 'return ' + code)` to avoid this error: `The Function constructor is eval  no-new-func`, not sure why

Comment: Because when you parse a string as code you might execute potentially dangerous code if you don't know what's in that string, so eslint warns against the use of eval or Function constructor to evaluate strings as executable code. But they both can be used safely if you know what you are doing.

Comment: There seems to be a problem when I have more than one line in the markdown file, I'm getting this error: `Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag`

Comment: I fixed it with this: `const htmlWrapped = '<>'.concat(html).concat('</>')
      const code = buble.transform(htmlWrapped).code;`

Comment: Yes that's the right fix ;-), I'd like it more like:
` const html = `<>${converter.makeHtml(md)}</>`;

Comment: I'm having trouble with complex markdown documents with code examples (Unexpected token error), it seems to be that special characters need to be escaped, I managed to do it for single and double quotes, not sure what else can be escaped

Comment: Can you update your question with further details or open another question?

Comment: Here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72017760/problem-transpiling-html-to-jsx-of-html-code-generated-by-showdown