# Problem Transpiling HTML to JSX of HTML code generated by showdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown

I'm using showdown to create some objects using the Markdown editor and in particular I want to include React javascript code in the markdown using the backtick ` ` characters, but my code is not working.

If I look at the markdown preview it's working fine, but when I try to convert it to JSX it breaks.

I can't figure out if it is an escaping error or something else. It seems it's trying to parse the code but it shoudn't, since it's inside a `<code> </code>` tag in the generated HTML.

Here is my code:

```js
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite"
import React, {useMemo} from "react"
import Showdown from 'showdown'
import { useStore } from "../store/Provider"
const buble = require('buble');

const MarkdownToJSX = ({ md }) => {
    // if (typeof md !== 'string') return null;
    const makeComponent = useMemo(() => {
      const converter = new Showdown.Converter({
        tables: true,
        simplifiedAutoLink: true,
        strikethrough: true,
        tasklists: true,
      });
      // wrap converted HTML in closures
      //   const html = <>${converter.makeHtml(md)}</>
      const html = converter.makeHtml(md)
      const htmlWrapped = '<>'.concat(html).concat('</>')
      const code = buble.transform(htmlWrapped).code;
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      const makeComponent = Function('React', 'return ' + code)
      console.log(makeComponent)
      return makeComponent;
    }, [md]);
  
    return makeComponent(React);
  };

function Bounties() {
    const store = useStore()

    return (
        store.bounties.map( bounty => (
            <div className="bounties" key={bounty.id}>
                <h2>{bounty.title}</h2> 
                <div >
                    <MarkdownToJSX md={bounty.body}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        ))
    )
}

export default observer(Bounties)
```

Here is an example of the problems I'm facing: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8fcgyb

Using the code form de Demo provided on the comments:

```
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite"
import React, {useMemo} from "react"
import Showdown from 'showdown'

import "primereact/resources/themes/lara-light-indigo/theme.css";  //theme
import "primereact/resources/primereact.min.css";                  //core css
import "primeicons/primeicons.css"; 
import { Button } from 'primereact/button';

import { useStore } from "../store/Provider"
// import Bounty from "./Bounty";

const buble = require('buble');

const MarkdownToJSX = ({ md }) => {
    // if (typeof md !== 'string') return null;
    const reg = /(?<=<code>).+(?=<\/code>)/gim;
    const makeComponent = useMemo(() => {
      const converter = new Showdown.Converter({
        tables: true,
        simplifiedAutoLink: true,
        strikethrough: true,
        tasklists: true,
      });
      // wrap converted HTML in closures
      let html = `<>${converter.makeHtml(md)}</>`;
      //Extra step to sanitize wrong text content
      html = html.replace(reg, (match) => `{"${match}"}`);
      console.log("HTML: ",html);
      const code = buble.transform(html).code;
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      const makeComponent = Function('React', 'return ' + code)
      console.log(makeComponent)
      return makeComponent;
    }, [md, reg]);
  
    return makeComponent(React);
  };
  
  function selectBounty( event, bountyId) {
    console.log(bountyId)
  }
  
  function Bounties() {
    
    const store = useStore()
    return (
        store.bounties.map( bounty => (
            <div className="bounties" key={bounty.id}>
                <Button 
                  className="p-button-outlined"
                  onClick={(event) => selectBounty(event, bounty.id)}>{bounty.title}</Button> 
                <div >
                    <MarkdownToJSX md={bounty.body}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        ))
    )
}

export default observer(Bounties)
```

If I enter `` console.log(`Hello ${world}` ) `` on the editor and try to convert, I get this correct HTML:

```
HTML:  <><h1 id="typeyourmarkdownbountyhere">Type your markdown bounty  here…</h1>
<pre><code>console.log(`Hello ${world}` )
</code></pre></>
```

But I get this error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: world is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (Bounties.js:32:1), <anonymous>:4:94)
    at MarkdownToJSX (Bounties.js:37:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16141:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20838:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22342:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4157:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4206:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4270:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27243:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26392:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26303:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26271:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25689:1)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25935:1)
    at flushSyncCallbacks (react-dom.development.js:11982:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:25490:1
eval @ VM103:4
MarkdownToJSX @ Bounties.js:37
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16141
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20838
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:22342
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4157
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4206
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4270
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27243
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26392
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26303
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26271
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25689
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25935
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:11982
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:25490
index.js:1 The above error occurred in the <MarkdownToJSX> component:

    at MarkdownToJSX (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:830:5)
    at div
    at div
    at observerComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:18376:76)
    at div
    at observerComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:18376:76)
    at StoreProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1387:5)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to write `{ observer }` as a string but without quotes, and JSX can't know that, since in JSX when you put something between curly brackets, it means it's JS code, no matter what tag embraces it, `buble` will transform it to:
`React.createElement("code", null, "import",  observer , "etc...")`
And observer is obviously undefined when you parse that function.

This should fix it:

```
body: `#Title1<br/> \`{"import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite'"}\`<br/>*Line2*`
```

Since you ned to explicitly tell JSX that you want everything inside those code tags to be evaluated as a `JavaScript` string type. This is just lean JSX not something related to buble or markdown escape.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-28fxjj)

Comment: The problem is that my HTML comes from the markdown of the editor converted to HTML `const html = converter.makeHtml(md)` and if I paste the code: `const html = converter.makeHtml(md)` in the markdown editor, I get the same error as in my demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8fcgyb

Comment: I'm not sure I get the problem, the `converter` converts markdown to  a String parsing the markdown symbols to html tags. That's it. If you then want to parse that code inot a react JSX working code, you need to make sure it's valid JSX. If you dont want to manually make it valid JSX syntax, you need some extra steps after the conversion to add `{" dangerous strings here"}` in place of text content.

Comment: My program is using the Showdown Markdown editor to allow the user to enter the markdown information, in there I want the user to be able to insert arbitrary code using the  markdown backticks used to insert code, this will be converted to `<code> <code>` tag by the HTML converter. What's inside the markdown code \` code \` backticks do not has te be valid JSX code,  it's just arbitrary code (javascript, c++ or any other prog. lang). I think this line `const code = buble.transform(htmlWrapped).code;` is failing because I believe is trying to validate the code inside the markdown backticks.

Comment: I think you are missing the fact that the moment you show code in React that code **HAS** to be evaluated unless you display it as a string :) Your best bet is just to make an extra parsing step after the conversion, and you wrap everything inside <code> tags in `{" here the text content "}`. You can do that with a regex and a replace.

Comment: Check the updated demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-28fxjj

Comment: Thanks Cesare, Exactly, I want it to be a string, it's just like here in stackexchange when I use the backticks to insert arbitrary code (e.g. `console.log(\`Hello ${world}\` )`. The code is not evaluated. The example you posted is giving me this error: "Error occurred
Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name"

Comment: SO does not use JSX, the example works fine to me, check again.

Comment: It still giving me this error: Error occurred
Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name

Comment: Are you on Safari ?

Comment: Yes that was the problem, I tried on Chrome and your example is working. Still I cannot make it work on my code. I'm using React 18.

Comment: What's the markdown that gives problems?

Comment: \` console.log(`Hello ${world}` \`

Comment: I updated the question with my new code and the error messages